# php echo without decoding Hex values

Tags: php

I want to output "\x68\x61\061"

```
$a = "\x68\x61\061"; 
echo $a
```

This does not result into "\x68\x61\061" in the output. How to fix this?

Comment: Single-quote it instead of double quotes.

Comment: This is explained in the [PHP manual on strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 4):

Escape your special characters, in this case backslashes, with another backslash.

```
$a = "\\x68\\x61\\061"; 
echo $a;
```

or use single-quotes instead.

```
$a = '\x68\x61\061'; 
echo $a;
```

[Reference](http://pt2.php.net/language.types.string)